# How to filter points from a strings?

Tags: java

I have a string

```
String ="...blah..."
```

I want to filter this string from 3 dots in the front and 3 in back to have like follows

```
String = "blah".
```

Whats the most effecient way to perform this sort of operation?

Comment: Your example is a bit weak. Can your string contain dots in the middle? Does it always have exactly three dots at the beginning and the end?

Comment: *"Whats the most effecient way to perform this sort of operation?"* 1) Programmatically 2) Expending no effort & asking strangers to do it for you.  It depends on your definition of 'effecient' (sic).

Answer (score 3):

Use `.replace(..)` (linear complexity)

```
str = str.replace(".", "");
```

You can also try the regex-version (not sure which will perform better):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.+", "");
```

Or of it is exactly 3 dots from the back and 3 from the front, use

```
str = str.substring(3, str.length() - 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have 3 dots and beginning and end, use [`substring`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

```
String foo = bar.substring(3, bar.length()-3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = "...blah...";
myString = myString.replace(".", "");
```